# jQuery UI Accordion and paging

Tags: jquery-ui, jquery-ui-accordion, jquery-ui-plugins

Has anyone had any luck getting any sort of paging plugin to work with the jQuery UI Accordion?  When I use SimplePager with it everything breaks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer turned out to be using Knockout.js which allows paging from a data point of view.

Answer (score 1):

I've written a simple class to paginate the accordion.
Check out http://pastebin.com/wZ8ztedJ

Comment: Sorry I didn't get a chance to try your solution so I can't safely award you the answer.