# Slide Page according to section with menu

Tags: jquery, css

I am working on a html site and want to make a function using jquery and css.

I want to slide the according to the side menu when clicked. When someone clicked on 2 number the page will slide to the number 2 block on the page.

Please see the image attached for more clear view what i want to do!

[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/POYpG.jpg)

Comment: A jsfiddle would be nice, could you provide some code, have  a look at this previous stack A/Q http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5666844/jquery-ui-accordion-and-paging

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**DEMO:** http://jsfiddle.net/gvee/LYqVk/1/

### HTML

```
<div id="content">
    <div class="section" id="section1">section 1 content</div>
    <div class="section" id="section2">section 2 content</div>
    <div class="section" id="section3">section 3 content</div>
</div>
<ul id="menu">
    <li> <a href="#section1">Section 1</a>

    </li>
    <li> <a href="#section2">Section 2</a>

    </li>
    <li> <a href="#section3">Section 3</a>

    </li>
</ul>
```

### CSS

```
* {
    margin: 0;
    border: 0;
    padding:0;
}
#menu {
    position: fixed;
    list-style-type: none;
    right: 10px;
    top: 20%;
    width: 100px;
}
#menu .highlighted {
    background-color: yellow;
}
#content {
    margin-right: 120px;
}
#section1 {
    background-color: red;
    height: 400px;
}
#section2 {
    background-color: blue;
    height: 200px;
}
#section3 {
    background-color: green;
    height: 800px;
}
```

### JQuery

```
$('a[href*=#]').click(function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    var id = $(this).attr('href');
    var scrollTo = $(id).offset().top;

    $('html,body').animate({
        'scrollTop': scrollTo
    }, 500);
});

$(document).scroll(function () {
    highlightSection();
});

function highlightSection() {
    // Where's the scroll at?
    var currentPosition = $(this).scrollTop();

    // Remove highlights from all
    $('a[href*=#]').removeClass('highlighted');

    // Loop over each section
    $('#content .section').each(function () {
        // Calculate the start and end position of the section
        var sectionStart = $(this).offset().top;
        var sectionEnd = sectionStart + $(this).height();

        // If the current scroll lies between the start and the end of this section
        if (currentPosition >= sectionStart  && currentPosition < sectionEnd) {
            // Highlight the corresponding anchors
            $('a[href=#' + $(this).attr('id') + ']').addClass('highlighted');
        }
    });
};

// Call on page load too!
highlightSection();
```

Comment: And if i want to add the background to show which block is viewing currently on screen.

Answer (score 0):

Give that block some id like id="blockTwo".
At the side menu on that number 2 make `<a href="#blockTwo">2</a>`

When you click it it will go to block 2 with that id.